# Acceleration/Reducing structure using a throttle

Tags: c#, algorithm, unity-game-engine

Recently, I am building a flight simulation controller using joystick, throttle, pedal, etc.

Among them, what we are currently trying to implement for throttle is as follows.

This Throttle has no Idle state, only 0 (Off) and Max speed states.

[image: Throttle form exam]

1. Throttle has a value between -1 and 1. If the value is greater than -1, the speed increases. However, depending on the step of the value, the maximum acceleration value must also have a constant step. Ex) value -1 ~ 0: speed 0~650, value 0 ~ 1: speed 650~1390...
2. As the throttle value increases, the speed of increase (acceleration) shall also increase, and conversely, the deceleration speed when the value decreases shall be constant.

The code that is still in the trial and error stage is as following:
(not yet familiar with the correction of acceleration step..)

```
void SetThrust()
{
     var revisionValue = throttle + 1;
     var outputRate = (revisionValue - 0) / (2 - 0) * 100;

     if (throttle > -1f)
     {
        //add some smooth or lerp increase * decrease speed amount
        increment = outputRate * throttleFactor;
        speedEase = (maxThrust - thrust) * speedReciprocal;
     }

     // Some logic for item2 (increase/decrease speed according to the input value))       
}


void CalulateMovement()
    {
        float gravityFallByPitch = gravityAngularFactor * Mathf.Sin(transform.eulerAngles.x * Mathf.Deg2Rad);

        rotateValue = new Vector3(pitch * pitchFactor - gravityFallByPitch, yaw * yawFactor, roll * (rollFactor * Mathf.Abs(roll)));
        lerpRotate = Vector3.Lerp(lerpRotate, rotateValue, lerpFactor * Time.fixedDeltaTime);

        transform.Rotate(lerpRotate * Time.fixedDeltaTime);

        if (throttle > -1f)
        {
            if (m_rigidbody.IsSleeping())
                m_rigidbody.WakeUp();

            gravityFallByPitch = gravitySpeedFactor * Mathf.Sin(transform.eulerAngles.x * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
            thrust = (increment+gravityFallByPitch) * speedEase;
            thrust = Mathf.Clamp(thrust, minThrust, maxThrust);
            m_rigidbody.AddForce(transform.forward * thrust);
        }

        else if (throttle <= -1f && m_rigidbody.velocity.magnitude <= 1)
        {
            m_rigidbody.velocity *= 0;
            m_rigidbody.Sleep();
        }
```

Thinking about the structure of the throttle and this functional structure,
I conclude that it is contradictory that acceleration and deceleration exist together in a key,
and that only the maximum of acceleration should be limited according to the range of throttle values (-1 to 1).

In response, I consider the logic of calculating Throttle's InputValue -1 to 1 as a percentage and limiting the speed range according to each percentage, and my math ability is at a disastrous level, making it difficult to calculate.

In addition, there is a question of whether there is a better structure than this method.

I would appreciate it if you could help me with this calculation or give me an opinion on another idea.

Thank you for help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

OP:

> Thinking about the structure of the throttle and this functional structure, I conclude that it is contradictory that acceleration and deceleration exist together in a key, and that only the maximum of acceleration should be limited according to the range of throttle values (-1 to 1).

Yes, you are on the right track.  The key is to ensure that **all** devices, from *throttle*, to *jet engine/propeller* and the resulting *thrust*, are all *separate* even though there is a relationship.

I recently had to do this with my flight sim, the only difference is that an autopilot (*PID Controller*) is controlling the throttle.  Whilst both throttle and thruster can be described by percentage values, they also have *independent discrete quantities*.  A *Sea Harrier FA2* jump jet for example, with its throttle at 100%, equally can be outputting 100% from its VTOL thrusters, however the throttle might also be described as a value from {1...10} whilst the VTOL thrusters can also be described as a value from **0..97 kN**.

This is my setup:

```
 PID   --->    Throttle ---> Thruster ---> force ---> acceleration ---> velocity
0..1           0-100%        0..97 kN
(auto pilot)   AI/joystick   VTOL engine
```

I introduced a delayed reaction between a change in throttle and the resulting engine output due to the engine having to ramp up/down to the commanded setting. e.g. a pilot quickly moving the throttle to max on take-off might experience a slight delay in force output from the engines as it revs up. I'm not sure how realistic it is but it was a nice feature to add since everything was separate anyway.

### See also

- *[PID controller-VTOL-throttle Integration for the Control of Force in Satisfying Autopilot-governed Altitudes in Phyics-based Simulations](https://mickyd.wordpress.com/2021/06/12/pid-controller-vtol-throttle-integration-for-the-control-of-force-in-satisfying-autopilot-governed-altitudes-in-phyics-based-simulations/)*
- [Clip 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3-NEC3TAJEY)
- [Clip 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x5NUmiR1Vg0)

Comment: Thank you for the good reference. I didn't know about PID. The remaining problems seem to depend on my mathematical ability to understand that algorithm...

Comment: @developoma thank-you.  One thing I forgot to mention, I introduced a delayed reaction between a change in throttle and the resulting engine output due to the engine having to ramp up/down to the commanded setting. e.g. a pilot quickly moving the throttle to max on take-off might experience a slight delay in force output from the engines as it slowly revs up.   I'm not sure how realistic it is but it was a nice feature to add since everything was separate anyway. :)

Comment: From what I hear, the throttle of a real aircraft usually has an IDLE to raise the output, so I think it is rather realistic that moving the throttle quickly from the Off stage will cause a delay time to raise the engine power.

Comment: @developoma oh kewl. :)